# Change of variables—Galilean transformation

Tags: variable, coordinate-transformation

I have a function of two variables, `f[x, y]`, and I wish to do a Galilean transformation, i.e., `y = z - v t`, where `v` is constant. Hence I am left with a function of three variables, `f[x, z, t]`.

I've spent a couple of days now trying to figure out how to do this and have gotten nowhere. Just trying replace all doesn't work. Can anyone help me out?

For example, sticking with 1D for simplicity,

```
v = 1
f[y] = Piecewise[{1, 1 > y > 0}]
Plot[f[y], {y, -5, 5}]

y = z - v t

(* Some code here which does the Galilean Transformation to turn f[y] into g[z,t] *)
(* A test is that g[z,0]=f[y] *)
Plot[g[z, 0], {z, -5, 5}]
Plot3D[g[z, t], {z, -5, 5}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Please review your code. There are quite a number of issues, like not properly giving function parameters as parameters, using `=` instead of `:=`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll demonstrate my approach with a different function `f` here:

```
f[y_]:=y^2
```

The easiest is to just define `g` like this:

```
g[z_,t_]:=f[z-v t]
(* or also allow v as parameter: *)
g[z_,v_,t_]:=f[z-v t]
```

**A more general approach** to perform the parameter substitution would be:

Define your Galilean transformation, so that it works for any number of parameters, as long as there is a `y` somewhere:

```
galilean[f_] := f/.y->z-v t
```

and apply it to get `g[z_,t_]`:

```
g[z_,t_]:=Evaluate@galilean[f[y]]
```

**Proof:**

```
f[y]
(* y^2 *)
g[z,0]
(* z^2 *)
```

or simpler:

```
f[y]==g[y,0]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked perfectly!

Comment: @Jay: You are very welcome!